# Displaying image uploaded via Django FileField()

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a Django model for coaching programs in my site, I want to be able to upload a thumbnail image for every program. I used FileField() for that and set the "upload_to=" to the static folder. I am trying to display the image in the site using django templates, I configured the 'scr' attribute in the  tag but I am getting a 404 on GET response when the HTML tries to get the image:

`[01/Jan/2024 21:13:00] "GET /fit/static/fit/coaching/program_imgs/article_img.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3818`

I just want to be able to display the images uploaded to the db in the site.
When I acess the folder that the image was uploaded, the image is there just like it should be, I don't know why I can't display it in the HTML.

Important note: I am creating the db objects for the articles directly via the django admin site.

here is my models.py:

```
class coaching_programs(models.Model):
    coach = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='coach')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=35, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True)
    text = models.FileField(upload_to='fit/static/fit/coaching/program_text/',null=True,blank=True)
    # i will put md files in this filefield() above.
    img = models.FileField(upload_to='static/fit/coaching/program_imgs/',null=True,blank=True)
```

my HTML/ django templates:

```
    {%for post in posts%}
        <div class="post">
            {{post.img}}
            <img src="../../../{{post.img}}" alt="">
            <p>{{post.title}}</p>
            <p>{{post.price}}</p>
            <p>{{post.description}}</p>
        </div>
    {%endfor%}
```

views.py:

```
def coaching(request):
    return render(request,"fit/coaching.html",{
        'posts':coaching_programs.objects.all(),
    })
```

I'm sorry if there is any english errors in this, I'm brazillian and a begginner using Django, so any feedback is very aprecciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all when you want to upload media to your server you must configure the server to tell it where to save the files

add in settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

in url.py adds

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
...
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

then in models.py

```
class coaching_programs(models.Model):
      ...
     text = models.FileField(upload_to='fit/coaching/program_text/',null=True,blank=True)
     img = models.FileField(upload_to='fit/coaching/program_imgs/',null=True,blank=True)
     # the downloaded files will have as root the MEDIA_ROOT configured in settings.py
```

finally in django templates

```
{%for post in posts%}
   ...
   <img src="{{post.img.url}}" alt="">
   ...
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: THANK YOU bro!!! It worked perfectly, may God bless you and have a happy new year!